# Optimizing MySQL table for sub-string search (one word records - dictionary)?

Tags: mysql

How to optimize MySQL table with roughly 1 million of records for sub-string search (%xxx, xx%, %xxx%)? All records contain just one word (11 characters avg, 41 max).

I know that query LIKE %xxx is problem but I do not see any way how to avoid it.

So question is: Is there any way how to help MySQL to minimize effort for these queries? Or Is there any other way how to query such data different way to utilize some index?

Available technologies: MySQL, PHP, Javascript (MySQL and PHP are commercially used so not possible to reconfigure specific way).

background: It is "complete" list of unique words used during last 15 years in literature written in my native language. I want to give users chance to find all relevant words by entering just part of the word (any part).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a standard MySQL index for sub-string matching. It won't work for anything except prefix matches.

You could maybe generate a `SOUNDEX()` for the word, but that is probably not what you want.

You could generate all possible substrings for each row and store them in another table. That would be a lot of rows (maybe 50 million), especially if you include single characters as substrings (EDIT: see below)

After that, you could try looking for a free text match library that does fuzzy matching to plug in to your application. I don't know of anything in PHP. FREJ is something in Java.

Quick and dirty solution:

1M rows * 11 characters = 22MB of memory (i.e., nothing).

Load it into memory and scan it.

EDIT: as suggested, you could just store substrings and index to the end of the string and then use prefix matching to return a candidate set. This will require only n index entries per word, where n is the word length.

For really efficient use of storage, you need to look at advanced techniques using n-grams [N-grams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram)

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. Idea about substrings is interesting. If I build list of all potential substrings ... it will give me base where I can apply prefix search ... and thats the way how to put index to the game. Quick check SUM of length gives me 13M characters. So 13M records. If I apply Index to this new bigger table will it be significantly more efficient to query 13M rows with index then 1M without?

Comment: Yeah - you can cut down the index size by using prefix search. Good idea. So that will be less rows. Index lookup should be a lot faster  than full-table-scan on 1M rows. But consider an in memory search solution.

Comment: Memory table sounds great but block the memory for something that can be without any hit for long time - I do not see it efficient. I just want to design this as good as possible to minimize potential performance impact. When I make it public it can generate too high load with full-scan queries above such a big table easily. Anyway, I like your original idea with sub-strings derived from original table which will be subject of standard prefix query utilizing index. Thank you.

Comment: Tested yesterday evening. Created table with 7M rows (table size 370MB = 210MB data and 160MB index) by adding all substrings into additional column. What is important: querying that substring column now MySQL utilize index so query duration went down from seconds to tens of milliseconds. Great. Thanks a lot @rghome.